# MacOSX: find out if a process (given a PID) is running in 32bit or in 64bit Intel mode

Tags: macos, unix, pid, mach-o

I have a PID and I want to find out if the process is running in 32bit or in 64bit Intel mode. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can do via [`NSRunningApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
[[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:pid] executableArchitecture]
```

returns the [Mach-O architecture constant](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Mach_O_Architecture).

This works only for GUI applications, though...