# Check if any running binary is 32 or 64 bit

Tags: c++, c, macos, architecture, 32bit-64bit

It is possible to check if an app bundle's binary process is running in 32 or 64 bit mode, as [answered in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335245/macosx-find-out-if-a-process-given-a-pid-is-running-in-32bit-or-in-64bit-inte), but I can verify that it only works with GUI processes.

However, I need to also check processes that don't have a GUI and is not part of a bundle.

So, programmatically, **without calling system functions or other executables**, how can I test if any process is running in 32 or 64 bit mode, given the process pid?

Comment: Why the C++ and C tags? Isn't your app written in Objective C?

Comment: No, it's in C / C++. Objective-C is only required on OSX for GUI applications. Daemons can use C or C++ and kernel extensions are almost always C++ and can not use Objective-C. Just because it's OSX does not mean you are limited to one language.

Comment: The question you linked to is in Objective-C.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes, it is, I can mix and match the languages and have found that the Objective-C method does not work for me, so am asking for a C / C++ method.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, thanks but since the binary could be a universal one containing both 32 and 64 bit code, the source to the File command will not help here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if process is 64 bit or 32 bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983962/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-process-is-64-bit-or-32-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally found the answer was already on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983962/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-process-is-64-bit-or-32-bit), for Carbon.
In order to use that code now, this include is required:

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
```

Also, it appears that the member to the process structure has changed from

```
proc->kp_proc.p_flags
```

to this:

```
proc->kp_proc.p_flag
```

Comment: Posted an alternative solution to the question you linked. You can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27929872/419275